# Using <br/> in tool tip and change the default color of a tool tip

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip

I am using default asp.net `ToolTip` property, the text is

```
This is Going to be a long text
Thats why we decided to split it.
```

but using `<br/>` to split the line doesn't work, it renders as a text, and I want it to break the line instead.

Here is my code:

```
Label lblActionText = new Label();
lblActionText.Text = "Helloooo Phaltu";
lblActionText.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
lblActionText.ToolTip =
    "This is Going to be a long text"
    + "<br/>"
    + "Thats why we decided to split it.";
```

Answer (score 4):

I've not tried this but would "System.Environment.NewLine" not do the job instead of the BR tag?

Comment: lblActionText.ToolTip = 
    String.Concat("This is Going to be a long text", Environment.NewLine, "Thats why we decided to split it.");

Comment: lblActionText.ToolTip = "This is Going to be a long text" + Environment.NewLine + "Thats why we decided to split it."; works in IE8 and Chrome for me. Is there anything else on your page that could interfere?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Firefox so can't comment specifically on it but there is an interesting read here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=358452 maybe Firefox just doesn't support newlines in tooltips?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to insert a line break inside a ToolTip.

```
lblActionText.ToolTip = " First text " + Environment.NewLine + " second text ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string value to a Tooltip, and that's why the HTML element `<br />` is not working.

However you can try this [ASP.Net AJAX TooltipExtender](http://weblogs.asp.net/cjdevos/archive/2008/03/29/asp-net-ajax-tooltipextender.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the line break character entity (`&#013;`).  It is easy to implement but the only problem is that this will work in IE & Chrome but not Firefox.

```
lblActionText.ToolTip = "This is Going to be a long text&#013;Thats why we decided to split it.";
```

**See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jafLf/**

Comment: Did you test it in Fire Fox ?

Comment: @BrunoLM; you can try my answer.

Comment: @Muhammad what is your answer??

Comment: did you see the answers list against your question :)

Comment: This works in Firefox now (not sure which version it started working in).  I use &#13; without the zero.

Answer (score 0):

This works only on IE but other browsers are not!!
If you want to have a customize tooltip then seach for jQuery tooltips to have a formatted tooltip

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with adding a table in the tooltip :)

Example: [ASP forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1245060.aspx/1?New%20Line%20In%20Tool%20Tip)

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET `ToolTip` property corresponds to the HTML `title` attribute.

In IE and Chrome you can simply do:

```
<span title="multiline
tool
tip">Mouseover me!</span>
```

However, that won't work in Firefox as it actually follows the [W3C guidelines for CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html).

> CDATA is a sequence of characters from
>   the document character set and may
>   include character entities. User
>   agents should interpret attribute
>   values as follows:
>
> - Replace character entities with    characters,
> - Ignore line feeds,
> - Replace each carriage return or tab    with a single space.

Your best bet (considering you also want to change the colour) would be to go with a jQuery solution such as [**QTip**](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) which gives you all the customisation you want and more..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the color of a tooltip with the default `title` attribute. For that the only way is to use a javascript generated tooltip.

There are plenty of plugins for jQuery such as:

- Dynamic tooltip

[image: Dynamic]

- Popup Bubble

[image: popup bubble]

- jQuery Horizontal Tooltips
- Coda Popup Bubble
- Awesomeness
- TipTip
- (mb)Tooltip
- vTip
- jGrowl
- jQuery Ajax Tooltip
- Digg-style post sharing tool with jQuery
- Input Floating Hint Box
- Simpletip
- qTip
- Orbital Tooltip

And many more, check them here: [**Stylish jQuery Tooltip Plugins Webdesign**](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)

You can also just create your own using javascript. Add a mouseover event on the element then show a hidden div over the element with whichever html elements you want, in whichever color you need.

It is also more safe to use a javascript approach for cross-browser compatibility.